# awk: first, split a line into separate lines; second, use those new lines as a new input

Tags: awk

Let's say I have this line:

```
foo|bar|foobar
```

I want to split it at `|` and **then** use those 3 new lines as the input for the further proceedings (let's say replace `bar` with `xxx`).

Sure, I can pipe two awk instances, like this:

```
echo "foo|bar|foobar" | awk '{gsub(/\|/, "\n"); print}' | awk '/bar/ {gsub(/bar/, "xxx"); print}'
```

But how I can achieve this in one script? First, do one operation on some input, and then treat the result as the new input for the second operation?

I tried something like this:

```
echo "foo|bar|foobar" | awk -v c=0 '{
        {
            gsub(/\|/, "\n");
            sprintf("%s", $0);
        }
        {
            if ($0 ~ /bar/) {
                c+=1;
                gsub(/bar/, "xxx");
                print c;
                print
            }
        }
    }'
```

Which results in this:

```
1
foo
xxx
fooxxx
```

And thanks to the counter `c`, it's absolutely obvious that the subsequent `if` doesn't treat the multi-line input it receives as **several new records** but instead just as one multi-lined record.

Thus, my question is: how to tell awk to treat this new multi-line record it receives as many single-line records?

The desired output in this very example should be something like this if I'm correct:

```
1
xxx
2
fooxxx
```

But this is just an example, the question is more about the mechanics of such a transition.

Comment: I would just use the two instances. If it's in a script (in terms of shell rather than `awk`), it doesn't really matter *how* complex it is.

Comment: Well, the question is not really how to achieve the result but more like is awk capable of solving this specific task at all? :)

Comment: No, AWK doesn't have that functionality. Separate fields by `|` and loop through them.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would suggest an alternative approach using `split()` where you can just split the elements based on the delimiter into an array and iterate over its fields, Instead of working on a single multi line string.

```
echo "foo|bar|foobar" |\
    awk '{
             count = 0
             n = split($0, arr, "|")
             for ( i = 1; i <= n; i++ )
             {
                 if ( arr[i] ~ /bar/ )
                 {
                     count += sub(/bar/, "xxx", arr[i])
                     print count
                     print arr[i]
                 }
             }
         }'
```

Also you don't need an explicit increment of `count` variable, `sub()` returns the number of substitutions made on the source string. You can just increment to the existing value of `count`.

As one more level of optimization, you can get rid of the `~` match in the if condition and directly use the `sub()` function there

```
if ( sub(/bar/, "xxx", arr[i]) )
{
    count++
    print count
    print arr[i]
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If you set the record separator (`RS`) to the pipe character, you almost get the desired effect, e.g.:

```
echo 'foo|bar|foobar' | awk -v RS='|' 1
```

Output:

```
foo
bar
foobar
[...an empty line
```

Except that a new-line character becomes part of the last field, so there is an extra line at the end of the output. You can work around this by either including a new-line in the RS variable, making it less portable, or avoid sending new-lines to `awk`.

For example using the less portable way:

```
echo 'foo|bar|foobar' | awk -v RS='\\||\n' '{ sub(/bar/, "baz") } 1'
```

Output:

```
foo                                                                    
baz
foobaz
```

Note that the empty record at the end is ignored.

Answer (score 1):

With GNU awk:

```
$ awk -v RS='[|\n]' 'gsub(/bar/,"xxx"){print ++c ORS $i}' file
1
xxx
2
fooxxx
```

With any awk:

```
$ awk -F'|' '{c=0; for (i=1;i<=NF;i++) if ( gsub(/bar/,"xxx",$i) ) print ++c ORS $i }' file
1
xxx
2
fooxxx
```